# Rhino Security - Configure multiple users

Tags: c#, rhino-commons, rhino-security

I am using Rhino Security and everything works fine when I configure the security settings as follows:

```
Security.Configure<User>(cfg, SecurityTableStructure.Prefix);
```

However, this depends on having a single User type that implements the IUser interface whereas my application has multiple types of "User". I tried using the above line twice with different user types but, predictably, this resulted in a duplicate mapping error...

Has anyone ever run into (gotten around) this issue?
Thanks in advance
JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Rhino.Security demands to be mapped to one and only one class, but you might be able to use inheritance to get around the problem.  If your system allows for customers and employees to login as different kinds of users then derive a Customer and an Employee class from the User class.